# Out of Memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your option

Tags: matlab

I have written a code for Log transformation of an image. But here on line 5, I'm getting errors each time. What to do?

```
%Log Transformation
figure;
L = 256;
I = imread('C:/Users/TASNEEM/Desktop/img1.JPG');
log_I = uint8(log(double(I)+1).*((L-1)/log(L)));
exp_I = uint8((exp(double(I)) .^ (log(L) / (L-1))) - 1);
subplot(2, 2, [1 2]); imshow(I); title('input');
subplot(2, 2, 3); imshow(log_I); title('\itlog(I)');
subplot(2, 2, 4); imshow(exp_I); title('\itexp(I)');
```

The error I get:

```
??? Error using ==> +-
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> C:\MATLAB6p1\work\Assignment\one.m
On line 5  ==> log_I = uint8(log(double(I)+1).*((L-1)/log(L)));
```

Or sometimes I get this error:

```
??? Error using ==> double
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> C:\MATLAB6p1\work\Assignment\one.m
On line 5  ==> log_I = uint8(log(double(I)+1).*((L-1)/log(L)));
```

Comment: How large is your image? (Type `whos I`) How much memory does `memory` tell you is available?

Comment: You might have other large variables defined. Consider using `clear` at the start of your script to clear the workspace.

Comment: Possibly you want to use element-wise operator  ./  instead of /